# Кеш веб-приложения

Tags: тестирование

Есть Веб приложение. Есть картинки. Если зайти в режиме инкогнито Chrome, загружаются с сервера. Если зайти в стандартном режиме повторно — disk cache, если обновлять страницу — memory cache. По-моему, так, как и должно быть.
Вопрос, почему в Chrome DevTools > Application > Cache я не вижу этих русурсов?

Во-вторых, картинки загружаются с кодом 200, хотя у них есть заголовок Etag. Получается он не срабатывает и есть другие механизмы работы с кешем?
Вернее не так: почему в Chrome 200, а в FireFox 304
Пожалуйста, подскажите

Comment: Возможно, ответ на последний вопрос есть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22733905)